# Is the order of labels in a select case statement important?

Tags: fortran

I was wondering about the performance of Fortran code as the number of list items in a case statement increases. I guess there's an upper bound set by the compiler for the number of list items, but for the applications I'm typically using case statements for, the occurrence of the list items is non-random, and so is the positional order important in the list. Specifically, will code be faster with the more frequently occurring items benefit from being ordered earlier in the list?

So will

`case ('common case', 'rare case', 'very rare case')`

run faster than

`case ('very rare case', 'rare case', 'common case')`

Comment: The Fortran standard certainly doesn't imply that there should be a speed difference resulting from the order of case selectors. There may well be, based on specific implementations, so if you care about a particular compiler then please give details about it. (If you don't care about a particular compiler, then I'm afraid you can't get a better answer than "possibly, possibly not".)

Comment: And to confirm, do you really mean `case (a, b, c)`, or `case(a); ...; case(b); ...; case(c); ...`?

Comment: I meant the former, so ```case (a, b, c)```. I'd seen that the standard is silent on the issue, and probably you are in the hands of the compiler.

Comment: Yes. It will be implementation dependent - and not just the "make" of the compiler, but also the compiler version and possibly other variables as well.

Answer (score 2):

The order of value ranges in a selector, and indeed the order of selectors within the case construct as a whole, does not define an order of evaluation of comparison.

In that sense, no, the order of `case(a,b,c)` against `case(c,b,a)` does not affect the performance of your code.

A compiler is free to compare selectors and value ranges within a selector against the case expression in any order or even some at the same time or not at all (in the final case if it knows the constant expression can never match), regardless of how written.

If you write `case(common, rare, inexplicable)` the compiler can see that as `case(prohibitively_expensive_comparison, compare_if_i_must, trivial_to_check)` and decide to compare in a corresponding order. Or the compiler may use profiling-driven optimization.

That said, if the compiler decides to compare in a linear way, sequentially, each value range as written, yes, you may see a (tiny) performance gain by ordering in terms of frequency.

To ensure a compiler may evaluate as it chooses, you must write code in such a way that there can ever be only one match.

In conclusion: test and profile your code. But be nice to readers and code reviewers who will struggle to understand your code much more than your compiler will.